# How to perform execute(@variable) in SSRS (or can this even be done)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have this SQL I created in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Select @query =  'Select LastName, FirstName, ' + @weekNumbersNull + '
from (
             Select LastName, FirstName, Hours, ''Week'' + 
             Case When DatePart(Weekday, Date) = 1 
             Then Cast(DatePart(ww, Date - 6) as nvarchar(max))
             Else Cast(DatePart(ww, Date - DatePart(Weekday, Date) + 2) as nvarchar(max))
             End WeekNo
             From Entry
             Where Date between ''11/1/2013'' and ''11/30/2013'') alpha
             pivot (
             sum(Hours)
             for WeekNo in (' + @weekNumbers + ')
             ) p 
             order by LastName, FirstName'
execute(@query)
```

(I left out the SQL that defines all the variables for brevity).
When I run it there, I get results.  So, I port this SQL to SSRS and under Datasets, I only see the name I gave the dataset with no columns:

[image]

Is there any way to get this to work in SSRS, or do I have to look for another way to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and modified my SQL thusly:

```
Declare @WeekStart DateTime
Declare @WeekEnd DateTime

Select @WeekStart = @DerivedStartDate
Select @WeekEnd = DateAdd("dd", 6, @WeekStart)

Create Table #TempTable (WeekOf DateTime, LastName nvarchar(max), FirstName nvarchar(max), Hours numeric)

While @WeekStart < @DerivedEndDate Begin
   Insert into #TempTable
   Select @WeekStart week, LastName, FirstName, 
      (
          Select sum(Hours) 
          From Entry x
          Where x.Date between @WeekStart and @WeekEnd and x.uuid = entry.uuid
       ) as TotalHours
   From Entry
   Where (
      Select sum(Entry2.Hours) From Entry as Entry2
      Where Entry2.UUID = Entry.UUID and Entry2.Date Between @WeekStart and @WeekEnd) < 40
   Or not exists 
   (
      Select 1 From Entry as Entry2
      Where Entry2.UUID = Entry.UUID and Entry2.Date Between @WeekStart and @WeekEnd
   )  
   Group By LastName, FirstName, uuid

   Select @WeekStart = DateAdd(dd, 1, @WeekEnd)
   Select @WeekEnd = DateAdd(dd, 7, @WeekEnd)
End

Select * from #TempTable
Order by WeekOf, LastName, FirstName
Delete #TempTable
Drop Table #TempTable
```

And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You will be fighting an uphill battle to have SSRS dataset fields defined dynamically like this. Depending on your requirements, I would try to settle on some fixed set of column names to return, and always return those, with or without data.

Getting dynamic SQL to run won't be a big problem. It's the dynamic nature of the fields returned that will throw SSRS. (Fixed column names will also make the report easier to design.)

It's hard to say without knowing the details of your requirements, but it looks like you are trying to do too much in the query; let SSRS do some of the work: I suspect that your query would work well in a [Matrix report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627441%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if you remove the `pivot` function: you can pivot your data in SSRS, and have individual columns for each week at the report level.

Comment: I had a nice little query that returned people who reported less than 40 hours in a given week.  A user wanted to add a date range to this, so I had to figure out how to get weekly totals for a date range, hence the pivot.

Comment: You could still add that to the query, handing in the dates as parameters.